# How to check the type of value in a CSV with d3.csv()?

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I was wondering if there is any way in D3 or plain JavaScript to check the data type on-the-fly when I read data in.

For example, if I want to read ["iris.csv"](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/curran/a08a1080b88344b0c8a7/raw/d546eaee765268bf2f487608c537c05e22e4b221/iris.csv) in using d3.csv() to make a box-plot, is there any way to check that `sepal_length`, `sepal_width`, `petal_length` and `petal_width` are numeric variables while `species` is a categorical variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's see one possible solution, using the CSV you linked:

```
sepal_length,sepal_width,petal_length,petal_width,species
5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,setosa
4.9,3.0,1.4,0.2,setosa
4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,setosa
4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,setosa
etc...
```

You cannot do a [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) straight away because `d3.csv` converts **everything** to a string:

```js
d3.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/curran/a08a1080b88344b0c8a7/raw/d546eaee765268bf2f487608c537c05e22e4b221/iris.csv", function(data) {
  var variables = data.columns;
  variables.forEach(function(d) {
    console.log("typeof " + d + ": " + typeof(data[1][d]))
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

However, we can use [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) to check if that string contains a number or not (warning: that won't work correctly with `null` or empty strings):

```js
d3.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/curran/a08a1080b88344b0c8a7/raw/d546eaee765268bf2f487608c537c05e22e4b221/iris.csv", function(data) {
  var variables = data.columns;
  variables.forEach(function(d) {
    console.log(d + " is: " + (isNaN(data[0][d]) ? "categorical" : "numeric"))
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see, we just need `data.columns` to get the headers and, after that, we just need the first row of values (which is `data[1]`, not `data[0]`). Actually, any row except the first (`data[0]`) can be used.

**EDIT**:

You asked in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48162798/how-to-check-the-type-of-value-in-a-csv-with-d3-csv/48164029#comment83337906_48164029):

> Have you got any more insight how to deal with missing value/null or empty string in the dataset?

A simple way is checking if the value is falsy...

```
!data[index][d]
```

... and going to the next row, until you find a proper value:

```
var index = 1;
while (data[index][d] === "null" || data[index][d] === "") {
    ++index;
}
```

Here is the demo, I put some `null`s and empty strings in the CSV, have a look:

```js
var csv = `sepal_length,sepal_width,petal_length,petal_width,species
null,,null,0.2,setosa
null,3.0,1.4,,setosa
null,3.2,1.3,0.2,null
4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,setosa
5.1,3.5,1.7,0.2,setosa`;

var data = d3.csvParse(csv);

var variables = data.columns;
variables.forEach(function(d) {
  var index = 1;
  while (data[index][d] === "null" || data[index][d] === "") {
    ++index;
  }
  console.log(d + " is: " + (isNaN(data[index][d]) ? "categorical" : "numeric"))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is perfect for now; however; have you got any more insight how to deal with missing value/null or empty string in the dataset? (or should I create a new thread?)

Comment: @bensw no need to post a new question, just check the edit.